# Parallel Apply on a deeply nested expression

Tags: parallelization, map, iterators

I have a deeply nested expression, i.e. something like `{{{{...}..}..}..}`, and I'd like to use `Apply` in a parallel fashion, e.g. `Parallelize[Apply[f,exp,{n}]]`. When I do this `Apply` is only parallelized at the top level, whereas I'd ideally like it to parallelize at the bottom-most level. Setting `Method->"FinestGrained"` didn't do the trick. Is there a clean way to do this or do I have to do something clunky like a combination of `Map` and `Apply`?

To be precise, the nested expression bottoms out at the same level everywhere. I.e. it is an expression of a form that would be generated by something like `Array[f,{i,j,k,l}]`. In such a case, I'd like to use `i*j*k*l` kernels during parallelization.

Comment: Why would you do this?  It seems unlikely to be more efficient.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what your actual data is like.  For example with `exp = {{{{a, b}, c}, d, e, f}, g, h}` `Apply` will only replace a single head.  Please provide a representative example.

Comment: @djp: It's more efficient because it'd be using more CPUs. I.e. the top-level has only a small number of elements (fewer elements than kernels).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I clarified my question.

Comment: Fair enough.  I've had the same problem; Transpose fixed it.

Comment: Transpose wouldn't do the trick in my example. Imagine something like `Array[f,{2,2}]` and I'd like to use four kernels.

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment to my original answer I now understand what you mean by "`Apply` is only parallelized at the top level."  Since [`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html) is an automatic process and since the `Method` option does not seem to have the desired effect I can only suggest a possible workaround, clumsy as it may be.

```
exp = Array[f, {1, 3, 2, 4}];

Parallelize[g[##, {$KernelID}] & @@@ Flatten[exp, 3]] ~ArrayReshape~ Dimensions[exp]
```

Obviously the flattening and reshaping is less than ideal but I do not know another method.

Comment: This answer doesn't address my question. The reason it's "working" is because the top level has 5 elements, and you only have 4 kernels. My question was parallelizing at the bottom-most level, i.e. in your example it would use 5 * 3 * 2 * 4 = 120 kernels. To see the issue with only 4 kernels, replace `{5,3,2,4}` with `{2,3,2,4}`. You will see that `$KernelID` shows only two kernels are being used.

Comment: @Mohammed This is the kind of information that would have been helpful to include in the question. :^)

Comment: Yes you are right. I used "parallelize at the bottom-most level" to indicate what I meant, but I see that it wasn't clear enough. I updated the original question with a concrete example. Thanks for your suggestions.